# std::vector::emplace_back bug when returning references (C++17)

Tags: c++, debugging, g++, c++17

I've been trying to trace a bug for 10+ hours now, and by now I'm starting to think that the bug can't be on my side. However, I have a feeling it could be me who's just forgetting or misunderstanding something.

I have a class member of type std::vector called temp_materials, and inside the constructor (when temp_materials is still empty), this code runs:

```cpp
    Material &stonewallbug = temp_materials.emplace_back(resource_lib.get_shader("DeferredGeometryShader"));
    stonewallbug.set_texture("texture_diffuse1", resource_lib.get_texture("StonewallDiffuse"));
    stonewallbug.set_texture("texture_specular1", resource_lib.get_texture("StonewallSpecular"));

    Material &containerbug = temp_materials.emplace_back(resource_lib.get_shader("DeferredGeometryShader"));
    containerbug.set_texture("texture_diffuse1", resource_lib.get_texture("ContainerDiffuse"));
    containerbug.set_texture("texture_specular1", resource_lib.get_texture("ContainerSpecular"));

    Material stonewall1 = temp_materials[0];
    Material container1 = temp_materials[1];

    Material stonewall2 = stonewallbug;
    Material container2 = containerbug;
```

If nothing goes wrong during the copying, stonewall1's contents should be equal to stonewall2, as should container1 to container2, correct?

However, I then insert all of them into a simple vector which's contents will be rendered later on:

```cpp
    // Using temp_materials[0]
    auto stonewall1node = SceneNode(stonewall1, resource_lib.get_mesh("Cube"));
    stonewall1node.set_transform(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
    m_scene_list.push_back(stonewall1node);

    // Using temp_materials[1]
    auto container1node = SceneNode(container1, resource_lib.get_mesh("Cube"));
    container1node.set_transform(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
    m_scene_list.push_back(container1node);

    // Using stonewallbug
    auto stonewall2node = SceneNode(stonewall2, resource_lib.get_mesh("Cube"));
    stonewall2node.set_transform(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)));
    m_scene_list.push_back(stonewall2node);

    // Using containerbug
    auto container2node = SceneNode(container2, resource_lib.get_mesh("Cube"));
    container2node.set_transform(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)));
    m_scene_list.push_back(container2node);
```

Now, I'd expect there to be 2 "container" cubes stacked on each other, and 2 "stonewall" cubes stacked on each other, but this is the result I'm getting:

[image: Result1]

If I however move the line `Material stonewall2 = stonewallbug;` to between the creation of stonewallbug and containerbug, I get the result I expect.

Noticing this, I made a very, very simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;

    std::string& ref1 = strings.emplace_back("1");
    std::string& ref2 = strings.emplace_back("2");

    std::cout << "ref1: " << ref1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ref2: " << ref2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "strings[0]: " << strings[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "strings[1]: " << strings[1] << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

And the result when running this is a lot of nonsense characters. However, if I output ref1 before ref2 is emplaced, it outputs the expected results. On [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) it says that vector's emplace_back is supposed to return a reference to the inserted element, but to me it doesn't seem like it's working like it should.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this just a *very* obvious bug in g++ 7.1?

Edit: I can't believe I spent so many hours on such an obvious thing... :)

Comment: Insertion invalidates references.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid now. Of course it does, it's recreating the underlying storage... Thanks! Add it as an answer if you want and I'll mark it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to be careful with references and iterators to container elements. Various mutating container operations *invalidate* references and iterators. The details vary by container and operation, but for `std::vector`, all inserting operations (such as `push_back` and `emplace_back`), as well as erasure from anything other than the end, invalidate both references and iterators in general (but see below for ways to avoid this).

Therefore, in the following code,

```
std::vector<T> v;

T & a = v.emplace_back(a, b, c);
T & b = v.emplace_back(x, y, z);
```

the second call of `emplace_back` invalidates the reference `a`. (And accessing an object through an invalid reference has undefined behaviour.)

To avoid invalidation in a `std::vector`, use the `reserve` and `capacity` facilities:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(2);
T & a = v.emplace_back(a, b, c);
T & b = v.emplace_back(x, y, z);
```

An insertion at the end does *not* invalidate if the new `size` is less than or equal to the current `capacity`.

Comment: "*all inserting operations ... invalidate both references and iterators*" - no, not ALL operations. Only operations that cause the vector to reallocate its internal array to grow its capacity, or to move elements around. Not EVERY insertion does that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I mean it in the sense that "you must assume they do", unless you write additional code to use the facilities I describe. Generally, if something *can* happen, you must assume that it does happen, unless you have a way of telling. In other words, saying that something invalidates your iterator isn't a *guarantee* that it invalidates, but something that you must assume happened (and cannot check). It's correct to say that push_back invalidates, because you cannot tell from its return value in isolation whether it did, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Does `std::queue` also suffer from this same invalidation of a reference when `emplacing` a new element?

Comment: @WBuck: `std::queue` isn't a container, but a container *adapter*. Its behaviour is determined by the choice of underlying container.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, with or without the `reserve`, https://ideone.com/tVSEQy