# Is vector.push_back(vector.back()+1) undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, vector, undefined-behavior

I want to append a new value to a c++ std::vector and this new value is relative to the last value in the vector. Can this code result in undefined behaviour?

```
std::vector<int> vector;
vector.push_back(1);
vector.push_back(vector.back() + 1);
```

Comment: What specifically about this code are you concerned about?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if the parameter of push_back is evaluated during the function call, it might try to read the value that is being appended to the vector.

Comment: It [can be a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253016/stdvectoremplace-back-bug-when-returning-references-c17) but not in this configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vector` isn't empty, so you're not invoking undefined behavior because of that.

The parameter to `push_back` is fully evaluated before the call is made, so that's not undefined behavior either.

Comment: For details about claim 2 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4638386/5987.